# Replace chart in PowerPoint with new version from clipboard (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a chart from Excel in my clipboard and in my PowerPoint I have a chart with exactly the same content but different values.

When I paste the chart from Excel to PPT the chart gets inserted with ugly styling etc. What I would like to do is to select the chart in the PPT that I would like to replace with my chart from the clipboard (excel) and keep the formating from the original chart in the PPT.

Is that something that can be done?

Comment: There is no such option in power point. However if you can edit the data of the chart (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-data-in-an-existing-chart-539c9840-7412-4da3-ab06-fcf318e996df?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Comment: Thanks! I actually export data to a excel-file that has the same name/path all the time but the file (underlying data) gets updated. So just creating a duplicated slide and update the data-reference actually seams to work.